# Custom list representation for list of objects

Tags: python, repr

I know that representation of an object can customized be using the `__repr__` magic method.

```
class A:

    ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'A(id={})'.format(self.id)
```

Is there a way to customize the representation when it is a list of these objects, such that it doesn't just print a list of the object's representation `[A(id=1), A(id=10), A(id=11)]`.

For example:

```
class AGroup:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst

>>> lst = [A(1), A(10), A(11)]
>>> grp = AGroup(lst)
>>> grp.lst
<Group of 3 A's>  # instead of [A(id=1), A(id=10), A(id=11)]
```

I was thinking of wrapping the list into another object before assigning to `self.lst` so that I can modify its repr. Any other idea?

Comment: It would be very, very confusing if Python allowed an object to take control of the `repr` of other objects.

Comment: You can try to monkey-patch the builtin `list` (highly inadvisable). Or you can create your own container class (much cleaner), which could simply wrap a `list` and then implement whatever behavior for `__repr__` you want

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes a container class is what I was originally thinking to do but I was wondering if there's another way

Comment: @user2357112 Im thinking something like an interface where a list of A objects would have a different display behavior versus any other list

Answer (score 0):

You can store the list passed to the `AGroup` constructor in an instance of a sub-class of `list`, so that you can override the `__repr__` method of the `list` sub-class to return an output in your desired format:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'A(id={})'.format(self.id)

class AGroup:
    class AList(list):
        def __repr__(self):
            return "<Group of %d A's>" % len(self)

    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = self.AList(lst)

lst = [A(1), A(10), A(11)]
grp = AGroup(lst)
print(grp.lst)
```

This outputs:

```
<Group of 3 A's>
```

Comment: The question shows an AGroup with elements having different ID values. Also, this is customizing the AGroup object's repr, not the repr of the list.

Comment: Indeed. Fixed then. Thanks.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oops was being too hasty. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to group class instance we need to overwrite eq, ne, and hash function. by giving the static hash value will treat all instances of this class as one object.

```
from collections import Counter
class A:
    def __init__(self , id):
        self.id = id
    def __hash__(self): return hash('A')
    def __eq__(self, x): return type(x) is A
    def __ne__(self, x): return type(x) is not A

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'A'


class B:
    def __init__(self , id):
        self.id = id
    def __hash__(self): return hash('B')
    def __eq__(self, x): return type(x) is B
    def __ne__(self, x): return type(x) is not B

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'B'


class AGroup:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        count = Counter(lst)
        self.lst = []
        for cl in Counter(lst):
            self.lst.append('<Group of {} {}\'s>'.format(count[cl] , cl))



lst = [A(1), B(10), A(11)]
grp = AGroup(lst)
grp.lst


["<Group of 2 A's>", "<Group of 1 B's>"]
```